# woocommerce price filter not working when change currency

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, filters

I am using woocommerce and i want to change filter price according to currency change.

when i change my currency all product change in currency but price range filter not change on shop page and other category page.

you can check link: http://nakodarakhi.clientprojects.in/shop/

Please solve the problem ASAP.

Thanks
Hemraj

Comment: The price filter is querying the prices in the database directly, and is going to ignore any filters you apply to the *display* of the prices. Whatever you’re using for switching currency would need to support changing how the price filter works. What are you using?

Comment: I am using FMA Woo Multi Currency plugin for currency change

Comment: You should contact its developer to see what your options are.

Comment: hello sir. i have changed my plugin. i'm using yith plugin for price filter but not working according to price https://nakodarakhi.com/shop. please check and revert back

Comment: Changing plugin doesn’t change my answer. If it doesn’t do what you want you need to take it up with the author.